# При касании элемента другим элементом выполнить действие

Tags: c#, winforms

На форме есть несколько элементов label расположенные внутри panel1 (label 1-4 голубые, label5 - желтый, labelst - зеленый, labelfin - красный)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С помощью этого кода, я могу перемещать label5(жёлтый) стрелками на клавиатуре

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(panel1_KeyDown);
    }
 private void panel1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
       
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            label5.Location = new Point(label5.Left - 10, label5.Top); 
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            label5.Location = new Point(label5.Left + 10, label5.Top); 

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            label5.Location = new Point(label5.Left, label5.Top - 10); 

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            label5.Location = new Point(label5.Left, label5.Top +10); 

        Refresh();
    }
```

Как уже стало ясно - это "игра" лабиринт. Но собственно главный вопрос! Как сделать так, чтобы при касании с другими элементами были действия, а не простое перемещение?

Comment: `Refresh`-то на кой? Я когда вижу в коде `Refresh`, сразу зверею. Зачем его лепят куда попало? И ведь я ни разу объяснений получить не смог. Просто лепят и всё.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Ну ведь расположение элементов изменилось, надо об этом сообщить куда следует, вдруг там не заметят и не перерисуют!! ))

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov , не зверейте пожалуйста, я это взял из примера, и сам не знаю еще нужен он или нет.

Answer (score 0):

не знаю правильно или нет, но догадался лишь до этого

```
if (label5.Bounds.IntersectsWith(label1.Bounds))
        {
            label5.Location = new Point(labelst.Left, labelst.Top);
        }
```

Comment: Ну выглядит логично. Просто вообще на WinForms обычно не пишут что-то настолько интерактивное, они на это не заточены :)